# Does the publish feature of Visual Studio 2010 push all files every time?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, publish, webdeploy

If I use the publish feature of VS 2010, does it move all files every time or only what changed?

Comment: Another useful publish feature worth mentioning is that you can have it wipe the remote site first, then republish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you choose `Replace matching files ...`, then no. (it copies only changed files)

If you choose `Delete all files...` then Yes. (it copies everything)